# Dynamic Sidebars & Echo

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

I can sucesfully get my dynamic sidebar to work like so:

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-first">
    <ul class="widget-area first">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'pop-photos-sidebar' ); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to get the sidebar to work with a different code that is inside a php code. I tried using the above `< ?php dynamic_sidebar( 'pop-photos-sidebar' ); ? >` code and it broke my site since the php dynamic_sidebar code is inside another php code.  So I tried making a $ function like so:

```
$newssidebar = dynamic_sidebar( 'pop-news-sidebar' );
            echo '<div class="sidebar sidebar-first">
                <ul class="widget-area first">
                '.$newssidebar.'
                 </ul>
             </div>';
```

This sucesfully displayed the dynamic side bar "pop-news-sidebar" but.. it is not inside the ul class widget-area first, or inside the div class sidebar sidebar-first.  How would I make my dynamic sidebar to properly be displayed in the ul class and div class listed above like it should be?  Would I even use echo? I didn't think it was necessary to paste the full code, but here it is anyways:

```
<?php
    if( fake if code ) {
        if( another fake if code ) {
            $newssidebar = dynamic_sidebar( 'pop-news-sidebar' );
            echo '<div class="sidebar sidebar-first">
                <ul class="widget-area first">
                '.$newssidebar.'
                </ul>
            </div>';
        }else if( fake else ) {
            echo 'some other code';
         }
    }

?>
```

Any help would tremendously be appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you post your actual code, so we can see your call to `dynamic_sidebar()` in context of your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to **echo** `dynamic_sidebar()`. End your `echo`, call `dynamic_sidebar()`, and then start a new `echo`. To make it easier, just close/reopen your PHP tags:

```
<?php
if( fake if code ) {
    if( another fake if code ) {
        ?>
        <div class="sidebar sidebar-first">
            <ul class="widget-area first">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'pop-news-sidebar' ); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else if( fake else ) {
        echo 'some other code';
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Wow, so simple yet effective and great, your the man Chip! I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes! :)